# Complicated way of Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I observe a different (different for me) way to write function of javascript or jquery,,,you guys kindly guide me about the working of this one.

```
(function () 
{
//some statements of javascript are sitting here
//some statements of javascript are sitting here
//some statements of javascript are sitting here
//some statements of javascript are sitting here
//some statements of javascript are sitting here
}());
```

Truly I'm not understanding `(function(){}());`.

No one is calling it but it is being called properly.

If any piece of tutorial you guys know, concerned to it, then tell me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). In other words, a function that gets executed when defined

Comment: I thought they were called anonymous and self-executing or something.

Comment: A.K.A. Self-Executing Anonymous Function

Comment: @Cthulhu - They have all sorts of names. Ben Alman coined IIFE, which probably most accurately describes the construct - the other names don't make it clear you have a function expression rather than a declaration.

Comment: Wow but javascript encourages some absolutely horrible practices. I'd never come across this one before, but that is just hideous coding.

Comment: @PaulMolloy: I don't see what's horrible about it but it's very common and  it makes total sense when JS only has function scope and the parenthesis are optional, just a convention, you can write: `function(){}()`

Comment: @PaulMolloy - It's not hideous at all. It's a very common way to introduce a new scope within a block (and it creates a closure to capture the value of variables in the parent scope too, which is very useful when declaring functions in loops e.g. event handlers).

Comment: @eclanrs do you mean (function(){}()); is replaced by function(){}()

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a function without a name is normally used to assign that function into a variable. A useful trick which allows you to pass the entire function around and call it later.
In this case it's not being assigned to anything, but the extra set of brackets after the braces are effectively calling the function immediately.